# Display a notice in cart page if specific products are in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, notice

how can we make this function below to check multiple product ids instead of just one id, how can we convert it to array ?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'bbloomer_find_product_in_cart' );
    
function bbloomer_find_product_in_cart() {
  
   $product_id = 17285;
  
   $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id );
   $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );
  
   if ( $in_cart ) {
  
      $notice = 'DON\'t Forget to Apply the discount coupon code you received to complete purchasing with the discounted price';
      wc_print_notice( $notice, 'notice' );
  
   }
  
}
```

We tried       `$product_ids = array("17285", "17302");` // but it doesn't work

we also tried this but not working too

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'ts_woocommerce_quantity_selected_numbe', 10, 2 );
function ts_woocommerce_quantity_selected_numbe( $product ) {
    $product_ids = array("15757", "15758"); // Here the array of product Ids

    if ( in_array( $product->get_id(), $product_ids ) ) {
        // In cart
        if ( ! is_cart() ) {
            $notice = 'DON\'t Forget to Apply the discount coupon code you received to complete purchasing with the discounted price';
      wc_print_notice( $notice, 'notice' );
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check cart items for one or multiple product Ids, displaying a notice, use instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'found_product_in_cart_display_message' );
function found_product_in_cart_display_message() {
    $product_ids = array(17285, 17302); // Array or product ids

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( array_intersect( $product_ids, array($item['product_id'], $item['variation_id']) ) ) {
            // Display a notice
            wc_print_notice( __("Don't forget to apply the discount coupon code you received to complete purchasing with the discounted price."), 'notice' );
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

For product id array which are in cart use this code,

```
$array_product_ids = array();

foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    $array_product_ids =   $product_id
}
print_r($array_product_ids);    // here you find all product id which are in the cart.
```

Comment: And how can we apply this to our example .. how after that print a message

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_cart','ts_woocommerce_quantity_selected_numbe', 10, 2 );
function ts_woocommerce_quantity_selected_numbe( $product ) {
     $array_product_ids = array();

foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    $array_product_ids =   $product_id
}
    if ( in_array( $product->get_id(), $array_product_ids ) ) {
        // In cart
        if ( ! is_cart() ) {
          // your notice here 
        } 
    }
}